# MySQL sub select ignores condition

Tags: mysql, sql

This query works good but ignores the **AND members.active='1'** condition completely.

It delivers always the same results, no matter if active is 1 or 0.

Any idea?

```
select amount, count(*) AS quantity
from
(
SELECT participations.member_number, COUNT(participations.member_number) AS amount
FROM participations
LEFT JOIN members
ON
participations.member_number=members.member_number
AND members.active='1'
GROUP BY participations.member_number
)
DT
group by amount
order by amount
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an other way to do it :

```
select amount, count(*) AS quantity
from
(
    SELECT participations.member_number, COUNT(participations.member_number) AS amount
    FROM participations
    LEFT JOIN members on participations.member_number=members.member_number 
    WHERE members.active='1'
    GROUP BY participations.member_number
)
DT
group by amount
order by amount;
```

Explanation :

with `WHERE` : After joining. Records will be filtered after join has taken place.

with `ON` : Before joining. Records (from right table) will be filtered before joining.

With an `INNER JOIN`, the clauses are equivalents.

Comment: He changed `AND members.active = 1` TO `WHERE members.active = 1`, which was what the OP should have done originally

Comment: @SelVazi that's how the answer should be , not just a query without explanation.+1

Comment: The LEFT JOIN returns reguar INNER JOIN result here. As intended?

Answer (score 1):

The issue might be with the AND clause in the LEFT JOIN statement. You can try moving the AND clause to the WHERE clause instead, like this:

```
FROM participations
LEFT JOIN members ON participations.member_number=members.member_number
WHERE members.active='1'
GROUP BY participations.member_number, members.active
) DT
GROUP BY amount
ORDER BY amount
```

This way, the AND clause will apply to the filtered data from participations and members tables, rather than to the whole data.

Comment: The LEFT JOIN returns reguar INNER JOIN result here. As intended?